# In Objective-C, exponential values from multiplying two large numbers

Tags: objective-c

When multiplying two large numbers I am getting exponential values.

```
double price=[priceperUnit.text doubleValue];
double quantity1=[quantity.text doubleValue];
double totalvalue=price * quantity1;
totalValue.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", totalvalue];
[dic setObject:@([totalValue.text floatValue]) forKey:@"Total Value"];
```

In dictionary I am getting these values:

> PriceperUnit = 1485500;
>     Quantity = 9;
>     TotalValue = "1.33695e+07";

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, you should be using `NSNumberFormatter` for *every* number that you want to display to users:

```
double price = 1485500;
double quantity1 = 9;
double totalvalue = price * quantity1;

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2;
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2;

totalValue.text = [formatter stringFromNumber:@(totalvalue)];
[dic setObject:@(totalvalue) forKey:@"Total Value"];
```

Also note that it is not a good practice to use `double` with money values. Operations with `double` are not suited for exact calculations. You should use `NSDecimalNumber` instead.

Comment: my problem is I want save totalValue float value (or) double Value in dictionary because I want to send it to server in double (or) floatValue

Comment: @narasimha That's exactly what I have done. Where is the problem? What is your issue with the exponential representation?

Comment: I am not able to answer another question so, I edit this question

Comment: @narasimha You cannot just change your question into a completely different question. If you start doing that, soon your account will be blocked completely.

Comment: @sultan i am not allowing to ask questions what can I do.Can you have a solution